# Amazon EC2: Unable to unmount and remove EBS drive file system

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems

I have create an EBS drive, attached it to the Instance and created file system using **mkfs.ext3**.
Now i want to unmount and delete the drive, i've tried many things but nothing seems to work. Although i am able to detach the drive from instance and delete using EC-2 Console,
but when i am checking partition using **df -hk** it is still showing the drive.

```
[ec2-user@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX ~]$ df -hk
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952   1075740   7097356  14% /
tmpfs                   304368         0    304368   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdf             30963708    176196  29214648   1% /media/newdrive
```

**And more over when i try to use any other command like "fdisk -l" or  and all or trying to browse the drive's folders, the putty session hangs.**
I am new to EC2 cloud and also to Linux.

Comment: And in EC2 unmount command is not working, and the **lvremove /media/newdrive** command is throwing error saying "Invalid path for logical volume"

Answer (score 5):

How about this? 
You need to run as: 
    `sudo umount /dev/xvdf`

Comment: in Amazon EC 2, unmount command is not present. I need to clean up the Drive details.

Comment: You will need to install the utility. What Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: Thanks for you comments. The problem is solved (a reboot always works)

Answer (score 2):

umount -dRf /media/newdrive

umount needs mountpoint not a devicetype like /dev/xvdf